# CMFCPropertyGridCtrl last item not drawn?

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I have a CMFCPropertyGridCtrl that I'm using in an options dialog box.  I have a method in my options dialog class called InitPropertyGrid().  This method clears any properties and populates the CMFCPropertyGrid objects (using a custom Settings object for the property values) and appends them to the grid.

When I open my dialog box the first time all the properties show correctly.  However, if I then close my dialog box and reopen it, the very last property is not drawn on the screen.  All other properties are drawn normally:

**First time:**

[image]

**All subsequent times:**

[image]

As you can see, the plus/minus icon is showing minus in both cases to indicated the section is expanded.  When the last item is not showing, clicking on the +/- icon once to contract and once to expand causes the last item to be correctly shown.

Note when I close the dialog box, I do not destroy it but just reshow it.  However immediately before calling ShowWindow on the dialog I call the InitPropertyGrid() (called by UpdateToCurrentSettings) method.

```
if(optionsDialog_ == NULL)
{
    optionsDialog_ = new OptionsDialog(settings_, this);
    optionsDialog_->Create(OptionsDialog::IDD, this);
}

optionsDialog_->UpdateToCurrentSettings();
optionsDialog_->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I can eliminate this problem simply by calling `myPropertyGrid.ExpandAll(TRUE)` at the end of the code where I initialize the property grid (InitPropertyGrid() for me).  This seems to force all the properties to expand.